# Social media icons not appearing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make social media icons appear on a site but for some reason they don't show up.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t8m68xw/) here.
HTML:

```
<span id="Facebook"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a>
<span id="Twitter"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a>
<span  id="LinkedIn"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a>
```

CSS:

```
#Facebook{
      height:26px;
      width:26px;
}
#Twitter{
      height:26px;
      width:26px;
}
#LinkedIn{
      height:26px;
      width:26px;
}

#Facebook a{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/facebook-icon-hover.png');

}

#Facebook a:hover{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/facebook-icon.png');
}

#Twitter{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/twitter-icon-hover.png');

}

#Twitter a:hover{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/twitter-icon.png');

}

#LinkedIn{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Linkedin-icon-hover.png');

}
#LinkedIn a:hover{
      background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Linkedin-icon.png');

}
```

Comment: If you have an ad blocker running it may be preventing display.  Disable the ad blocker for the pages you're working on.

Comment: @user2182349: I don't have ad blocker. The reason I think it does not appear is because I have no text between the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. Close your spans.

Comment: if you write something into <a></a> the icon appear. But it's a bad way to add a icon... try to use <i class=""> such as this: try to use <i class=""> such as this: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: You actually don't even need the `span` here. Everything can be done with `a`: `<a href="#" target="_blank" id="Facebook"></a>` as far as you declare it as `block`.

Answer (score 5):

You have some errors that are stopping it from working.
Firstly, this might just be an accident when putting it on StackOverflow, but you never close the spans:

```
<span id="Facebook"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a></span>
<span id="Twitter"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a></span>
<span  id="LinkedIn"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a></span>
```

Secondly, you are trying to add width and height to the spans, which are by default an inline element:

```
#Facebook, #Twitter, #LinkedIn {
      height:26px;
      width:26px;
      display:inline-block;
}
```

And lastly, you have the background image applied to the `<a>`, but they have no width or height:

```
#Facebook a, #Twitter a, #LinkedIn a{
    background-size:contain;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8j39go1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#Facebook,
#Twitter,
#LinkedIn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
}
#Facebook {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/facebook-icon-hover.png');
}
#Facebook:hover {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/facebook-icon.png');
}
#Twitter {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/twitter-icon-hover.png');
}
#Twitter:hover {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/twitter-icon.png');
}
#LinkedIn {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Linkedin-icon-hover.png');
}
#LinkedIn:hover {
  background-image: url('http://paksef.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Linkedin-icon.png');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="Facebook"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="Twitter"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="LinkedIn"></a>
```